# C++ possible to use move sematics to move data from one vector to another

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

The code below copies data from one vector into another. If the vectors are large then I guess this is expensive. Is it possible to use move semantics here to copy data from one vector into another?

```
std::vector<double> newData(Shape.Size(), 0);
std::vector<double> oldData = a->getData();
std::copy(oldData.begin(), oldData.end(), newData.begin());
```

Comment: It is possible to move data from one vector to another; the result will of course be that the source vector will only contain moved-from data, i.e. the data in it will be changed. Is that OK for your scenario?

Comment: @Angew do you mean that the source vector will contain `garbage` data as the original data has been moved?

Comment: `move sematics to copy data from one vector to another` the whole point of move is avoiding copies...

Comment: @Borgleader acknowledged and updates thanks

Comment: in this example there is no difference between copy and move, since vector contains type which is not impacted by move.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the algorithm `std::move` instead of `std::copy`:

```
std::move(oldData.begin(), oldData.end(), newData.begin());
```

It will still transfer elements by elements, but will move them instead. Don't forget to pre-allocate the vector with the right size to avoid moving elements around too much.

Comment: I understand that `std::move` moves the elements if possible, and copies otherwise. `std::copy` will always copy. Will `std::move` actually move them in this case?

Comment: @blacksheep In case of `double`s, moving is no different from copying. You could say `double`s are always copied.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is this just for doubles (why?) what other types does it apply to? thanks

Comment: @blacksheep moving element don't actually move them. There is no "moved" memory. Move semantics is about moving ownership from a scope or an object to another.

Comment: @blacksheep double are not owner of anything, so moving is the same a copy. Moving a whole vector will actually transfer the ownership of the underlying buffer, saving memory allocation.

Comment: @blacksheep Actual moving (e.g. moving `std::vector`s) is usually about ripping resources (e.g. heap-allocated blocks) out of the old object to use them for the new object. For `std::vector`, a heap-allocated block of the old object is used for the new object (and after the move, the old object doesn't own the block anymore). `double`s don't own any resources, they're just sequences of bytes.

Comment: @blacksheep Moving really only makes sense when dealing with pointers.  If you have something like  a double you have to make a copy since there is nothing to move.  If you have something like a `std::vector` that has a pointer to some memory then when you move what you do is copy the pointer into the new vector so you *move* the ownership of the resource.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do it with [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator).

```
std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(oldData.begin()), 
          std::make_move_iterator(oldData.end()), 
          newData.begin());
```

---

As [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302594/c-possible-to-use-move-sematics-to-move-data-from-one-vector-to-another#comment97333850_55302671) said this doesn't make much sense for `vector` of built-in types; copy is performed in this case at last. You might want to *move* the `vector` directly, e.g.

```
std::vector<double> newData = std::move(oldData); // move construction
```

or

```
newData = std::move(oldData); // move assignment
```

Comment: This is somewhat pointless for a vector of doubles. OP should move the whole vector, not its content.

Comment: @songyuanyao thank you, I understand - how do you move the vector directly?

Comment: @blacksheep Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided example move or copy there is no difference, since values in vector do not perform any spatial actions during move (it a double).

Here is reasonable example:

```
 using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;

 constexpr size_t n = 100;
 std::vector<FooPtr> data;
 data.reserve(n);
 std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data), n, FooFactory);

 std::vector<FooPtr> dst;
 dst.reserve(n);
 std::move(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::back_inserter(dst));
```

Note that

```
 dst = std::move(data);
```

Will be faster since data buffer simply will be reassigned to the other vector.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/pJnmrWYe40hLRYNE

Other answer uses `make_move_iterator`. This is practical if used with other algorithms. With copy/move is not very practical.

Comment: thank you what do you mean by `spatial action` in this context?

Comment: I've provided example with `shared_ptr` to show that move not only copies value, but also clears original. If you try do same thing for double you will see that simply copy is created.

Answer (score -1):

I assuming you are confused about move semantics. If you must keep your old data belong to old place, there are no way to use move semantics. Move semantic means move data out from old to new.

Additional GMT 18:50

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

    const int LEN_SHAPE = 1024;
    std::vector<double> a;
    int n = LEN_SHAPE;
    while (n--)
    {
        a.push_back( ((double)std::rand() / RAND_MAX) * std::numeric_limits<double>::max() );
    }

    std::vector<double> newData(a.size(), 0);
    std::vector<double> oldData( std::move( a ));
    std::copy(oldData.begin(), oldData.end(), newData.begin());

}
```

**std::vector oldData( std::move( a ));** is a move semantic, check after this what remains in vector *a*.